# Pass Viewbag element (int) into a list collection index

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Exer_RoutineList[ViewBag.RC].Name)
```

I hope this line of code is self explanatory enough.  I want to pass the value from a viewbag as the index to a List Collection.  Doesn't work, which I guess should be obvious.  What would be the best way to pass this in?  I am sure I will make it more complex then it needs to be.

Comment: Tried that :-/  Error:An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Comment: Ok, try putting RC in a viewmodel and pass model.RC in.

Comment: If you want to put that as the answer I will mark it as such.  Thank you!

Comment: Give @Satpal the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast `ViewBag.RC` to int

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Exer_RoutineList[(int)ViewBag.RC].Name)
```

To solve **An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation**,

```
@{
    int RCIndex = (int)ViewBag.RC;
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Exer_RoutineList[RCIndex].Name)
```

Comment: This works but seems bad practice. I would recommend avoiding ViewBag and opting for putting RC in a view model. but +1 for a workaround tho.

Comment: @Anon, I completely agree with you. This is just a workaround so that OP doesn't get stuck